# Can't find definition of compute_all_xxx functions in QEMU repository for i386 target?

Tags: qemu, emulation, x86-emulation, eflags

I was reading the source code of Qemu and wonder how Qemu emulate eflags for x86 processor, in the `target-i386/cc-helper.c` file I found that functions like `compute_all_addw` do the job, I want to know how Qemu implements those functions but I can not find the definition of all these functions. Did I miss something? Help please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

QEMU is using a trick here that it does fairly often -- using the C preprocessor to create multiple very similar functions without having to write them all out by hand.

In this specific case, the code is in target-i386/cc_helper_template.h:

```
static int glue(compute_all_add, SUFFIX)(DATA_TYPE dst, DATA_TYPE src1)
{
    int cf, pf, af, zf, sf, of;
    [...]
}
```

where `glue()` is a macro which just sticks its arguments together. `SUFFIX` and `DATA_TYPE` are defined earlier in the .h file based on the value of `SHIFT`. `target-i386/cc_helper.c` then `#include`s the template .h file multiple times, defining `SHIFT` differently each time. This results in function definitions for `compute_all_addb`, `compute_all_addw`, `compute_all_addl` and `compute_all_addq` being generated from the single template.

In general if you can't find a function definition in QEMU's source code with 'grep' the chances are good that it's being autogenerated like this -- searching for a substring of the function name may help.